# How does flash pass a scaleX event down to it's children

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can anyone tell me, or point me to reading about, how a ScaleX/ScaleY event propagates down to the children of display object? I want to step in at some point and "re-scale" one of the children of a display object that has just been scaled with it's parent. I can't find any event that is fired, and ScaleX and width setters don't seem to be getting called on the child objects. I'm working on an ActionScript Project (not Flex) in FlashBuilder.

Comment: If you want a `ScaleEvent` to be fired, you'll have to extend a class and make a few custom overrides: `override public function set scaleX( val:Number ):void { if ( this.dispatchEvent(...your event here...) ){ super.scaleX = val; } }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted, there is no resizing event, and children scale with their parent (expected behavior).

If you wish to scale the container, and have the content children remain the same size on screen, you have to loop over the children and do one of the following to each child:

- Apply to it the inverse of the transform matrix you used to scale the container
- Scale it by 1/**scale**, where **scale** is factor you multiplied the parent scale by.

Scale changes on the parent change its whole coordinate space, so if you want your children to stay the same size ***and*** stay in the same place relative to the parent's (0,0) point, you need to apply the 1/scale to their x and y positions also.

Comment: Giving this the answer as it's what I ended up having to do. I hate that the child object can't manage how it's own children are managed when an "outside force" (parent object) effects it's scale.

Answer (score 1):

scaleX, width, height, etc. are synchronous operations and there is no event fired. If you absolutely have to capture it in the setters, try overriding the setters in child components.

I did try that and it doesn't seem to work, if a property of a parent DisplayObject is being modified, its child components are not being touched. I guess it makes sense.

If you have access to parent components then you could intercept the setters over there.

Comment: To expand a touch, when you scale something, it's not an event that propagates anywhere. All that happens is that Flash changes the content of that parent's transform matrix. Then later, the next time a render occurs, when Flash redraws the child it concats the parent's transform to the child's, and thus the child inherits the transform. But nothing is inherited in terms of events or properties.

Comment: I tried overriding scaleX, transform, width, and x, and none of those seem to be called in the child object. I'm also listening for a render event on the child and not getting that either. The parent and child objects are all scaling up (via scaleX,scaleY). Seems like this is a problem that would have been solved a long time ago.